# Scala MaxMind IP Lookups with Scala

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, scala-collections, maxmind

I want to write a scala code which use the Database MaxMind GeoIP2 in order to identify the location and other characteristics of Internet users. I'm using Eclipse. My technical environment is perfectly fine. I want to use Scala MaxMind IP Lookups, it works with MaxMind's databases for looking up geographic location, ISP, organization, and domain from an IP address..

This is my function, which must be applied to a list of IP addresses :

```
package geoip


import com.maxmind.geoip.Location
import com.snowplowanalytics.maxmind.iplookups.IpLookups

import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.log4j._

import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf

object ipTracking {

  def parseIP(ip : String, ipLookups : IpLookups): List[String] = {

    val lookupResult = ipLookups.performLookups(ip)
    val countryName = (lookupResult._1).map(_.countryName).getOrElse("")
    val city = (lookupResult._1).map(_.city).getOrElse(None).getOrElse("")

    val latitude = (lookupResult._1).map(_.latitude).getOrElse(None).toString
    val longitude = (lookupResult._1).map(_.longitude).getOrElse(None).toString

    return List(countryName, city, latitude, longitude)

  }
```

The only error here is that IpLookups is not recognised as a type : **not found: type IpLookups**

For the rest, that should be good. Any help please ?

Comment: please provide your build file with maxmind related lib scope

Comment: FaigB : What have I to do exactly please ?

Comment: build.sbt or pom.xml file from your project

Comment: What does it have in common with apache-spark?